# Need help with the formula of the normal to a surface when using Stokes' theorem!

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When using stokes theorem how do we find the normal to a surface? What is the formula for the normal if the surface is parametrized and what is the formula when the surface is not parametrized.

Also if out surface is the union of two surfaces, then what is the formula for the normal to the surface e.g is $S=S1 \bigcup  S2$ and $S1$ and $S2$ have been parametrized what if the formula for the normal?

Answer (score 0):

If the surface is parametrized as $f(u, v)$ then the normal at $f(a, b)$ can be found as 
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(a, b)\right) \times \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a, b)\right)
$$
If the surface is given as an equation $g(x, y, z) = 0$, then the normal at $(a, b, c)$ can be found by calculating 
$$\nabla g(a, b, c)$$
In both cases, remember to take into account the length and positive / negative direction of the normal vector.

If your surface $S$ is the union of two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$, then for any point lying on one and not the other you use the above rules. If the point is on both surfaces, then you need to be more clever, and what you need to do changes from case to acse. In the worst case, if they intersect at an angle, then there *is* no normal vector along the intersection.